# AWS Ubuntu Server Causes Download PHP file

Tags: ubuntu, php, amazon-web-services

While development i have uploaded `index.php.bak`  and tried to access the `index.php` from browser it was downloading the complete `PHP` file from server. I immediately deleted `index.php.bak` , but still file getting downloaded from server.

I delete cache from my browser as well as deleted history.. Asked few friends to access file .. Dam Still getting downloaded.. 
DELETED file and again uploaded file but still its getting downloaded. I deleted it again , still getting downloaded..

```
ubuntu@domU:/var/www$ ls -la index.php
ls: cannot access index.php: No such file or directory
```

**Other Files PHP are working perfect !**

Any one what is issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandeep,

This typically means that PHP isn't configured properly.   Apache isn't passing PHP files to the php engine.   Double check your php / apache install.